# How to use RxJava to decrease the rate of events generated by button's tap?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

One of the tests executed by QA team is frenetically tapping on some button to make sure that only one event will be executed. Is it possible to use RxJava for that ensure this behavior? I've tried reading [this backpressure page](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Backpressure) from RxJava but I found that really hard to understand. Also, I don't see how I would emit an event from button's onClickListener - everything I think ends up creating a new Observer instead of emitting a new event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way for achieve it, is to throttle the events. You can use the [`throttleFirst` operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/sample.html): you basically define a window in which only one event will be triggered.

If you use [RxBinding library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) you can create a stream from your click, and you could have something like:

```
RxView.clicks(button).throttleFirst(600, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    .subscribe(empty -> { // your action});
```

So, after you click on your button, for 600 milliseconds any other clicks will do nothing, and you can prevent a double action.

**EDIT**: If you can't use `RxBinding` you can create your own `Observable` in this way:

```
Observable<View> clickEventObservable = Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<View>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super View> subscriber) {
            mButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
                if (subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) return;
                subscriber.onNext(v);
            });
        }
    });
```

**NOTE**: This implementation is for RxJava 1, but you should avoid it (you should not use `create` for creating an `Observable` in RxJava 1), but you can use RxJava 2, where using `create` is totally fine.

Comment: That's perfect, simple and efficient. The only problem to me is that RxBinding is API 17+ and, unfortunately, we still need to support API14 :/

Comment: You can also take a look at the `RxView.click()` implementation [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/ViewClickObservable.java):

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll take a look on that!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a mix of `debounce()` to only fire after the user is finished with its input. Then only take the `first()` event and keep subscribed with `repeat()`. The last two together will ensure that your click event was handled before another one can be observed.

```
RxView.clicks(button)
      .debounce(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
      .first()
      .repeat()
      .subscribe();
```

You just have to take care of unsubscribing from this `Observable` by yourself, maybe using `repeatWhen()` instead, because completion won't unsubscribe you anymore.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this with RxBinding because ```first()``` requires an argument and I wasn't sure what should I pass to it.

Comment: That would be Rx2 specific. `firstElement()` would be used instead.

Comment: Got it! Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 0):

For that you don't need to use RxJava, you can simply use instance variable as an indicator, using that you can check whether action is in progress for previous click and if so just ignore events.

Comment: This is what I've been doing so far but, since we are migrating to a reactive architecture and we want a simpler code to read, I think Rx is the best way to got. Sorry if I don't make it explicit in the question